# How to Achieve Slow Motion Effect in After Effects as seen in Kygo's Firestone Video

Tags: after-effects, slowmotion

This effect should be simple to achieve, however I'm having difficulty with time-remapping (should I be using this function at all?)

The effect happens right after 1:45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called the "Time Warp" effect. You should check out [this](https://youtu.be/ZJTaCeUFKaM?t=57s) video from "Fenchel & Janisch" for a tutorial on how to apply this effect.